# Resetting the session variable in php

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have the following form on "test.php".

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['ph']))
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        $_SESSION['ph'] = $_POST['ph'];
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>  
    <form method="POST" action="order.php" id="custphoneform">
        <label for="PhoneNumber">Enter Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="number" name="ph" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The "order.php" looks like this:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['ph']))
    echo ($_SESSION['ph']);
?>
```

The first time I load the `"test.php"` and input the phone number it works perfectly and gives me the correct output on `"order.php"`, but the second time onward, `"order.php"` gives me the same value which I had entered the first time even though I input a different value. I refreshed the page, same result.

I closed the file and reloaded it, still same value. Why is it behaving that way and how do I correct it? I want session to change value whenever a new number is entered which is not happening.

Comment: You're posting to `order.php` but setting the session variable in `test.php`.

Comment: The snippet of php on `test.php` is unlikely to do anything unless somewhere else you post back to `test.php` - the form action points to `order.php` so all the session setting should be on that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the new value to `SESSION` ON your `order.php` page like below:-

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['ph'])){
  $_SESSION['ph'] = $_POST['ph']; //change value of phonenumber inside SESSION
}
if(!empty($_SESSION['ph'])){
   echo ($_SESSION['ph']);  
}
?>
```

Also change `test.php` code like this:-

```
<?php
session_start(); // no need to do other stuff
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>  
    <form method="POST" action="order.php" id="custphoneform">
        <label for="PhoneNumber">Enter Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="number" name="ph" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Karan Gupta  glad to help you:):)